# Node.js + Espress + MySQL as Document Store (results)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, nosql

I have created a express App in Node.js

- express v4.16.2
- mysql v2.15.0

and i use MySQL as a Document Store

```
Columns    
id: integer
value: JSON
```

when i query the MySQL Database via mysql I get the result:

```
RowDataPacket {
id: '1',
date: '2018-02-25T17:48:52.000Z',
value: '{"name": "Andreas", "username": "andreaslacza", "gender": "Male"}'
},
// ... and so on
```

you can see my JSON is nested under values, but i need an output as follows to work with it in mustache/handlebars:

```
RowDataPacket {
"id": 1,
"date": "2018-02-25T17:48:52.000Z",
"value": {
    "name": "Andreas",
    "username": "andreaslacza",
    "gender": "Male"}
},
```

Comment: as `value` is coming as string, you need to use `JSON.parse` on `value` property

Comment: @suraj.tripathi how can i do that for all values?

Comment: What does `typeof RowDataPacket` output ? can you call `toString()` on it ?

Comment: @EvyatarMeged its the output Object from mysql, i can loop through it in mustache, but in the Object i must parse only the value and create a new json for it but i dont now how

Answer (score 0):

The following snippets assume you're using something like `async/await` with JavaScript though this will work the same if you're using callbacks and promises.

Lets assume you're using something like this to get the info from your database

```
// Get data from our DB using the `mysql` library...
var dbResult = await dbRequest();

var data = JSON.parse(dbResult.value);
```

You'll then be able to take the `dbResult.value` object and convert it into JSON as we have done above. This will allow us to use it as a JavaScript object like any object.

We can then inject it into a handlebars template and use something like the following. This assumes you pass it into handlebars with the object named "data" though it might also be "user" or even "this".

```
<p>{{data.name}}</p>
<p>{{data.username}}</p>
```

Which will render

```
Andreas
andreaslacza
```

Answer (score 0):

You need iterate through result array and apply `JSON.parse` on every value.

Like this

```js
'use strict'
let resultData = [
 {
  id: '1',
  date: '2018-02-25T17:48:52.000Z',
  value: '{"name": "Andreas", "username": "andreaslacza", "gender": "Male"}'
 },{
  id: '1',
  date: '2018-02-25T17:48:52.000Z',
  value: '{"name": "Andreas", "username": "andreaslacza", "gender": "Male"}'
 }
];

resultData.forEach(function(entry) {
 entry.value = JSON.parse(entry.value);
});

console.log(resultData);
```